# Среднее арифметическое

Tags: c++

Есть код, который вычисляет время функции
В main это время вычисляется 10 раз.
Далее надо все сложить и разделить на 10 (то есть, найти среднее). Вот в этом проблема. Как можно написать? Сейчас в результате получается -7.84591e+297, что, конечно, не верно
Еще была попытка писать не

`for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)  ex.measureTime(i);` , а `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)  t[i] = ex.measureTime(i);`
Но тогда программа дает примерно 6 результатов (из 10) и выскакивает исключение (из-за неверного размера массива?)

experiment.cpp

```
#include "experiment.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int experiment::foo(int n){
    int s {0};
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i+=1) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j+=1) {
            s += i * j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

double experiment::measureTime(int n) {
    steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
    foo(n);
    steady_clock::time_point t2 = steady_clock::now();

    duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds\n";
    return time_span.count();
}
```

statistics.cpp

```
double statistics::meanTime(double* t, size_t z){
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
        x += t[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Average time is " << x / z << " sec" << std::endl;
    return x / z;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "experiment.h"
#include "statistics.h"

int main(){

    int i{ 0 };
    int z{ 10 };
    size_t n{ 10 };
    
    experiment ex;   
    statistics stat;

    double* t = new double[i];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)  ex.measureTime(i);   
    
    stat.meanTime(t, n);

    delete[] t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скажите, а вот тут

```
int i{ 0 };
....
double* t = new double[i];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)  ex.measureTime(i);   
stat.meanTime(t, n);
```

1. Сколько памяти вы выделяете для массива?
2. Вы вообще в него что-то пишете, в этот массив?

Итог - вы суммируете непонятный мусор...

И еще - не понимаю, что вы *хотите* посчитать, считая `ex.measureTime()` для совершенно разных размеров задачи?... Какой смысл в этом усреднении?

Comment: measureTime вычисляет время foo. В main я с помощью цикла вывожу 10  раз эти измерения (они разные). Далее мне надо найти среднее

Comment: Так, похоже, требуется разжевать... Вы 1. не выделили место для массива. 2. не сохраняете результаты измерений в массиве. Ну и 3. - ваши измерения имеют смысл примерно как усреднение времени падения мяча с разных этажей 10-этажного здания - результат попросту ни о чем...